# Add shortcut for multiple terminal commands?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I find myself doing this too often - navigate to a folder, "Open Terminal Here", then "mate .", then "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"

I was wondering if it's possible to add a button to the finder toolbar that when I click it runs those two commands for me for the folder that I'm currently in?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following AppleScript should work, which you can save as an application and put in your Finder toolbar.

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set folderPath to (quoted form of POSIX path of (target of front window as alias))
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script "cd " & folderPath & "; mate .; python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
        end tell
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps like [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) that can do the text input for you. Another option might be to add a text substitution into the Language & Text System Pref under the Text pane.

There's a free Automator action, [Open Terminal Here](http://www.macworld.com/article/47839/2005/11/openterminalhere.html) that seems like it should accomplish the first part.